# Deeper contextual understanding of Isaiah 14:29b's reference to "serpent's root" , "viper" , "flying serpent"

Tags: translation-philosophy, context, symbolism, layers-of-meaning, metaphor

> Isaiah 14:28-30 New American Standard Bible 1995
>
> 28 In the year that
> King Ahaz died this [a]oracle came:
>
> 29 “Do not rejoice, O Philistia, all of you,
> Because the rod that struck you is broken; For from the serpent’s root
> a viper will come out, And its fruit will be a flying serpent. 30
> “[b]Those who are most helpless will eat, And the needy will lie down
> in security; I will [c]destroy your root with famine, And it will kill
> off your survivors.

> Isaiah 14:28-30 New King James Version
>
> 28 This is
> the [a]burden which came in the year that King Ahaz died.
>
> 29 “Do not rejoice, all you of Philistia, Because the rod that struck
> you is broken; For out of the serpent’s roots will come forth a viper,
> And its offspring will be a fiery flying serpent. 30 The firstborn of
> the poor will feed, And the needy will lie down in safety; I will kill
> your roots with famine, And it will slay your remnant.

I might just be asking questions about the obvious, and also just being overly nitpicky but here goes.

By keeping context in mind, we can infer that the Isaiah 14:29a's broken rod very likely refers to Isaiah 14:28's statement about kingdom of Judah's
King Ahaz's death.

I would like to get a deeper contextual understanding of Isaiah 14:29b's reference to the following 3 phrases:

- serpent's root
- viper
- flying serpent

I am a little Uncomfortable with associating the aforementioned 3 phrases to the Davidic-Kingly lineage culminating in Jesus Christ, The Messiah.
The reason why I'm uncomfortable is that
all 3 of the aforementioned phrases are associated with the serpent which is the enemy of Jesus Christ as per Genesis 3:14-15

> Genesis 3:14-15 New American Standard Bible 1995 14 The Lord God said
> to the serpent,
>
> “Because you have done this, Cursed are you more than all cattle, And
> more than every beast of the field; On your belly you will go, And
> dust you will eat All the days of your life; 15 And I will put enmity
> Between you and the woman, And between your seed and her seed; He
> shall [a]bruise you on the head, And you shall bruise him on the
> heel.”

> 14:28-30 The Westminster Leningrad Codex 28 בִּשְׁנַת־מ֖וֹת הַמֶּ֣לֶךְ
> אָחָ֑ז הָיָ֖ה הַמַּשָּׂ֥א הַזֶּֽה׃
>
> 29 אַֽל־תִּשְׂמְחִ֤י פְלֶ֙שֶׁת֙ כֻּלֵּ֔ךְ כִּ֥י נִשְׁבַּ֖ר שֵׁ֣בֶט
> מַכֵּ֑ךְ כִּֽי־מִשֹּׁ֤רֶשׁ נָחָשׁ֙ יֵ֣צֵא צֶ֔פַע וּפִרְי֖וֹ שָׂרָ֥ף
> מְעוֹפֵֽף׃
>
> 30 וְרָעוּ֙ בְּכוֹרֵ֣י דַלִּ֔ים וְאֶבְיוֹנִ֖ים לָבֶ֣טַח יִרְבָּ֑צוּ
> וְהֵמַתִּ֤י בָֽרָעָב֙ שָׁרְשֵׁ֔ךְ וּשְׁאֵרִיתֵ֖ךְ יַהֲרֹֽג׃

However, in light of the fact that Isaiah 14:29-32 is explicitly a specific Judgement against the Philistian nation, could some please provide a deeper contextual understanding in regards to Isaiah 14:29b's reference to the following 3 phrases?

- serpent's root
- viper
- flying serpent

Answer (score 1):

The historical background to Isa 14:28ff is provided by 2 Chron 18 involving the defeat of Tiglath-Pileser and the death of Ahab at the battle of Ramoth-Gilead.

Ellicott provides a useful reference here:

> (29) **Rejoice not thou, whole Palestina**.—Better, Rejoice not thou,
> Philistia, all of thee; i.e., give not thyself wholly to rejoicing.
> Here, as in Exodus 15:14, “Palestina” is used, not in the wider
> meaning with which we are familiar, but specifically as the country of
> the Philistines. The historical circumstances connected with the
> “oracle” before us are found in 2Chronicles 18:18. The Philistines had
> invaded the low country (Shetphēlah), and the district known as the
> Negeb, or “south” of Judah, in the reign of Ahaz. He had called in the
> help of Tiglath-pileser, the Assyrian king, to assist him as against
> Rezin and Pekah (Isaiah 7), so probably against these new invaders.
> Sargon (who succeeded Tiglath-pileser, B.C. 723) invaded Ashdod in
> B.C. 710 (Isaiah 20:1; Records of the Past, vii. 40). Sennacherib
> records a like attack on Ashkelon and (according to Rawlinson’s
> interpretation) Ekron (Records of the Past, vii. 61). With these data
> we are able to enter on the interpretation of Isaiah’s prediction.
>
> **Because the rod of him that smote thee is broken**.—The “rod,” as in Isaiah 10:24, is the power of Tiglath-pileser. The Philistines were
> exulting in his death, or in that of Ahaz as his ally, as though their
> peril was past. They are told that their exultation was premature.
>
> **Out of the serpent’s root**.—The three forms of serpent life (we need not be careful about their identification from the zoologist’s
> point of view) may represent the three Assyrian kings named above,
> from whose invasions the Philistines were to suffer. Each form was
> more terrible than the preceding. The fiery flying serpent (Isaiah
> 30:6; Numbers 21:6), which represented Sennacherib, was the most
> formidable of the three. So in Isaiah 27:1, the “piercing serpent,”
> the “crooked serpent,” and the “dragon” are symbols of the Assyrian
> power. Some critics, however, led chiefly by the first words of the
> next verse, find in the three serpents—(1) Ahaz, (2) Hezekiah, (3) the
> ideal king of Isaiah 11:1-9.

In this case, I agree with Ellicott.